# Access 2016 navigation buttons appear selected when they are not

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

In a new Access project I have a new navigation control. I set up some buttons and when I tested it in form view the buttons don't behave like they should.

The best way to describe the problem is visually:

[image: Example of problem]

As you can see, buttons appear to stay selected when they are not and this visual state is cleared by the highlight function of waving the mouse over the buttons.

**How do I stop this and get normal button behavior?**

Comment: What you are describing is quite abnormal behavior for form control buttons. How did you set these up in the first place? It almost looks like the primary problem is the `Hover Color` property, but for some reason it is sticking? Its probably in your best interest to just fiddle with the property sheet as much as you can to see if anything will fix it, or possibly create a new button and see if the issue persists. If not, you *might* just be able to copy the format of the new button to the old ones and solve the problem that way? ..And I assume these are `Button`(s) and not `Toggle Button`(s).

Comment: These buttons were auto-generated by Access from `Create > Navigation > Vertical tabs, Left` .  I just made a fresh one and it displays the same behavior. The colors are set by the default `Design > Colors > Blue`. I have changed the theme and colors. I have messed with all the properties but this happens on new navigation forms or the custom one I have tweaked.

Comment: I just added a `_click` handler to a button with a breakpoint to verify. I stepped through and made sure it ran `Form.Repaint` after a click and the deactivated button remained highlighted. (:-C)

Comment: This is only happening on some PCs.